# Worse or Worst, which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Could you please tell me which sentences with “worse” and “worst” below are correct?

1. He realizes that he missed the train. And **worst**, there is no train until next weekend.
2. He realizes that he missed the train. And **worse**, there is no train until next weekend.

Comment: What do you already know about the words "worse" and "worst".  What would you choose?  What about if it was  "better" or "best"?

Comment: @JamesK: thank you for the hint. I choose “worse”. Is it the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Worse` is used in the comparison. You would be comparing something to another thing.

whereas, `Worst` is a finalizing statement.

Comment: Alternately, "worst" can be used when comparing 3 or more things, and indicating the item that is the most bad/least optimal.

Comment: Please improve your answer. "Whereas" is a subordinating conjunction, not an adverb. And the phrase "finalizing statement" is unclear.

Comment: What is the comparison being made in the original question?